# TypeScript - isolatedModules and JSON import

Tags: json, typescript

We are using a Babel to compile our TypeScript files and we want to use *isolatedModules: true* in our *tsconfig.json* as it is a recommended way. It, for example, throws an error when you try to re-export an interface. This is a necessary feature as Babel TypeScript compiler doesn't allow that too.

However, we need to import a JSON file in our TS file. The issue is that *tsc* will throws the following error:

```
Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.
```

Any idea how to import a JSON and keep type-checker happy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a TypeScript bug and the fix was just merged to master: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28207

It should be available on 3.1.4+.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You should accept this answer, give Bruno the credit he deserves ;)